# Firefox quantum, disable search in address field

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

I've been looking everywhere but cannot find a way to disable the search from the Address field in the Firefox Quantom.

No problem adding a search bar, but that doesn't negate the search from the address bar.

I'm currently on 57.0.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to disable search in the address bar (aka *awesomebar*) by:

- going to `about:config`;
- searching for the `browser.urlbar.suggest.searches` preference;
- setting it to `false`.

You may notice that there are other `browser.urlbar.suggest.*` preferences there. You can tweak them to personalize your urlbar suggestion experience.

**Update**: to disable searching when typing an address (e.g. the URI fails to resolve and it tries to use a search engine) also disable `keyword.enabled` in the preferences. To prevent the bar from guessing/fixing the typed URI (e.g. typing *fred* is changed to *fred.com*) there's [another pref](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/0a895028f74cffa67561150d10700abca8a931d8/modules/libpref/init/all.js#1148), `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled`. It needs to be set to false to disable URI fixup.

Comment: I changed that to false but it only removed the search suggestions. It still takes you to the default search engine if you type a non-url and click the arrow.  I checked out the other browser.urlbar settings and none of them that I modified changed the undesired behaviour. thanks.

Comment: I've added another detail to the answer: this pref (along with the other ones) should do what you want.

Comment: keyword.enabled=false  worked to keep the browser from visiting the search engine. It did have a different effect.  I used just the word 'frank' in the url address bar. After a short period it timed out and gave me a message that it could not to the destination in time 'url: http://www.frank.com/'.  The message is from our macafee gateway but I'll try it on my personal device too to see if it still tries to add information to the address that wasn't included.

Comment: Searching for just the word 'frank' still looks for frank.com when not using a network with macafee gateway. I hope it always checks the local web server first. :)

Comment: Ok, there seems to be [another pref](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/0a895028f74cffa67561150d10700abca8a931d8/modules/libpref/init/all.js#1148), `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled`, that needs to be set to false to disable URI fixup. Sorry for not catching this earlier :)

Comment: Yes, that does it. I know it wasn't specific to the original question but you should add that info into your answer. thanks again.